# Pointers to Members equivalent in c

Tags: c

There is an array of structures that I want to sort by the value of specific fields. The data types in the fields are identical. In c++ I used pointer to member to avoid rewriting same sort for different fields.

```
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    int year;
    int price;
} example_struct;

void sort_arr(example_struct a[5], const char* usr_field) {
    int example_struct::*field = nullptr;

    if (strcmp(usr_field, "id") == 0)
        field = &example_struct::id;
    else if (strcmp(usr_field, "year") == 0)
        field = &example_struct::year;
    else if (strcmp(usr_field, "price") == 0)
        field = &example_struct::price;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 - i; j++) {
            if (a[j].*field > a[j + 1].*field) {
                buff = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = buff;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main {
    example_struct a[5];

    fill_arr(a); //somehow filling the array
    sort_arr(a,"year");
}
```

I want to know, whether this code can be somehow emulated on C and how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro to get the offset to the member you want to compare, then use pointer arithmetic to get the value of the member. Note you won't get any type information for that member, just the offset into the struct so you'll want to ensure you know the sizes of the member fields.

So to do your compares, you could do this:

```
void sort_arr(example_struct a[5], const char* usr_field) {
    size_t offset;
    if (strcmp(usr_field, "id") == 0)
        offset = offsetof(example_struct, id);
    else if (strcmp(usr_field, "year") == 0)
        offset = offsetof(example_struct, year);
    else if (strcmp(usr_field, "price") == 0)
        offset = offsetof(example_struct, price);

    ...
    if (*((int*)((char*)&a[j])+offset) > *((int*)((char*)&a[j+1])+offset)) {
        ...
```

It may help to define some macros to make the member access a little more pleasant to work with.

```
#define memberat(ref, offset, membertype) *((membertype*)((char*)ref)+(size_t)offset)

if (memberat(&a[j], offset, int) > memberat(&a[j+1], offset, int))
```

If you're dealing with members of different types, you'll have to use function pointers to handle the comparisons since how they are compared will differ.

Comment: Could you please explain how addressing in if statement works? Particularly why should i cast &a[j] to char*?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic on any pointer depends on the type of the pointer. `&a[j]` is a `example_struct*` so any arithmetic on a pointer of that type would offset by `sizeof example_struct`. Given a byte offset, you would need to cast the pointer to `char*` to get the correct address, do the arithmetic, then back to the expected type of the member at that offset.

Answer (score 0):

The marco `offsetof` is the answer, but sorting this way is overly hard and not especially type-safe, (if one changes the type, one will probably not receive an error or maybe even a warning.) This is typical C code to sort; one has one function that picks out the `int` in the `struct` that one wants for each `int` value and compares for `qsort`.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_* qsort rand */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <string.h> /* strcmp */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */

struct ExampleStruct { int id, year, price; };

static void fill(struct ExampleStruct *const a) {
    assert(a);
    /* <http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html> */
    a->id = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 99998 + 1) + 1;
    a->year = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 119 + 1) + 1900;
    a->price = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 999999 + 1) + 1;
}

static void print(struct ExampleStruct *const a) {
    assert(a);
    printf("%05d\t%d\t$%d\n", a->id, a->year, a->price);
}

static void for_each(struct ExampleStruct *const a, const size_t a_size,
    void (*const action)(struct ExampleStruct *const)) {
    size_t i;
    assert(a && action);
    for(i = 0; i < a_size; i++) action(&a[i]);
}

static int cmp_int(const int a, const int b) { return (a > b) - (b > a); }

static int cmp_id(const void *const va, const void *const vb) {
    const struct ExampleStruct *const a = va, *const b = vb;
    return cmp_int(a->id, b->id);
}

static int cmp_year(const void *const va, const void *const vb) {
    const struct ExampleStruct *const a = va, *const b = vb;
    return cmp_int(a->year, b->year);
}

static int cmp_price(const void *const va, const void *const vb) {
    const struct ExampleStruct *const a = va, *const b = vb;
    return cmp_int(a->price, b->price);
}

int main(void) {
    struct ExampleStruct a[5];
    size_t a_size = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
    for_each(a, a_size, &fill);
    printf("Sorted by id.\n");
    qsort(a, a_size, sizeof *a, &cmp_id);
    for_each(a, a_size, &print);
    printf("Sorted by year.\n");
    qsort(a, a_size, sizeof *a, &cmp_year);
    for_each(a, a_size, &print);
    printf("Sorted by price.\n");
    qsort(a, a_size, sizeof *a, &cmp_price);
    for_each(a, a_size, &print);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```